# Write windows event log from javascript

Tags: javascript, event-viewer

Does anyone know how to write an event to the windows event log using javascript (or whether it's even possible)?

Thanks,
Genaro

Comment: I sincerely hope it is not possible.

Comment: Javascript running in a browser? No; On the desktop/wsh? Yes - LogEvent of WScript.Shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible from plain javascript running in a browser.  You would probably need a browser plug-in that linked to native code.